# How to convert a dictionary into a pandas dataframe with key and values in two separate columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a python dictionary in this format.

```
d = {1: {1, 2, 3},
     2: {4, 5}}
```

I want to convert it into a pandas dataframe in this format.

```
Expected Output:
    Source      Target
    1           1
    1           2
    1           3
    2           4
    2           5
```

I have tried doing this using list comprehension

```
d = {1: {1, 2, 3}, 2: {4, 5}}

df=pd.DataFrame([[key,v] for key, value in d.items() for v in value], columns=["Source", "Target"])
print(df)
```

But, is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df.explode`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    1: {1, 2, 3},
    2: {4, 5}
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns=['Source', 'Target'])
df = df.explode('Target')
```

Which gives

```
   Source Target
0       1      1
0       1      2
0       1      3
1       2      4
1       2      5
```

Here, we create the dataframe with multiple values for each `Target`, and explode then creates a new row for each value in target.

Notice that the index still reflects the original dataframe, so we can use:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

To reset it to

```
   Source Target
0       1      1
1       1      2
2       1      3
3       2      4
4       2      5
```

Which combined gives us

```
df = df.explode('Target').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Explode is not working as it requires the data in "Target" to be of list type

Comment: @ankit729 Are you running this exact code? It works on my end (pandas 1.2.4). From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) "This routine will explode list-likes including lists, tuples, sets, Series, and np.ndarray. "

Comment: Yes, I am running this exact code. Explode is working only if dictionary values are of type list, not working for set, or even tuple. No problem by the way, I changed the value type to list before creating the dataframe.

Comment: I am working on a lower version of pandas (v1.1.5)

Answer (score 2):

You could create the DataFrame from each key:value pair in the dictionary and then `concat` them together.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Source': k, 'Target': tuple(v)}) for k,v in d.items()],
          ignore_index=True)
```

Or, you can use the `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` constructor, and `stack`, with a bunch of renaming

```
(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
   .stack()
   .reset_index(-1, drop=True)
   .rename('Target').rename_axis(index='Source')
   .reset_index()
   .astype(int))
```

---

```
   Source  Target
0       1       1
1       1       2
2       1       3
3       2       4
4       2       5
```